# sort visible and related hidden rows in a Bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table, made with bootstrap 3.
I have 2 kinds of rows, one with 4 td's, I use the first of them to display the following row which is hidden by default. (shows data about the previous row)

all of this works fine. BUT, the Bootstrap "sort" function (by clicking on the header rows) doesn't work as expected. It sorts ALL the rows, included the hidden ones, and my system does not work anymore... (when I click then on my main row, the following row is NOT a hidden one... :( )

Does anyone have an idea on how I could solve this problem?

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>show data</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>adress</th>
    <th>buttons</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="mainRow">
      <td class="clickArrow"></td>
      <td>my name</td>
      <td>my adress</td>
      <td>some buttons</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan=4>THE DATA !!!!</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.subRow').hide();
  $('body').find('.clickArrow').html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>');
  $('body').on('click','.clickArrow',function(){
    if($(this).html()=='<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>'){
      $(".clickArrow").html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>');
      $('.subRow').hide();
      $('.mainRow td').css('background-color','#DDDACE');
      $(this).parent('tr').find('td').css('background-color','white');
      $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>');
      $(this).parent('tr').next().slideToggle("slow");
    }else{
      $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>');
      $(this).parent('tr').find('td').css('background-color','#DDDACE');
      $(this).parent('tr').next().slideToggle("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

I don't know what is really going on with the "sort" function from Bootstrap.
Maybe the solution is to disable the bootstrap sort system, and implement mine.

I'm just wondering if someone already had this problem and found a decent solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

There is jquery plugin for this

You can sort your table based on table header

Try jquery datable plugin
 http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap

Comment: thanks, i saw that before, but i think you didn't understand my question... i'm not looking for a way to sort my table... what i'm looking for now, is a way to disable the sortWrapper from bootstrap .table class... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have some scss for you that you can apply to have the sorting buttons show up. Then all you have to do is to implement the sorting mechanism with jquery.

```
table {
    thead,
    tfoot {
      tr {
        th {
          position: relative;
        }
        th.sorting {
          padding-right: 1.5em;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        th.sorting.asc::before {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        th.sorting.desc::after {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        th.sorting::before,
        th.sorting::after {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: -2px;
          display: block;
          opacity: 0.4;
          padding-bottom: inherit;
          font-size: inherit;
          line-height: 180%;
        }

        th.sorting::before {
          right: 0.75em;
          content: '\2191';
        }
        th.sorting::after {
          right: 0.25em;
          content: '\2193';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Add .sorting to  tag to show the sorting. And .asc and .desc class to show which direction the sorting is happening